# Copying files between two windows servers through jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am working on a project where i want to copy the compiled file (which compiled through jenkins) from one windows server to another through jenkins. Jenkins is installed on a windows server and after building the code, those compiled file should be copied to another windows server through jenkins. Is there any way to achive it?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins might be able to do it, via the script steps running the scp command; however, if this is part of a build, I would suggest attaching the file(s) to a project, and distributing them through the maven repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my project is on Windows server and applications are also windows related so build and deployment will happen through jenkins using MSDN. I need to build the code and use the compiled files to copy on two different windows servers. Any good way to do that?

Comment: Well, you can use Jenkins in the CI role, but MSDN is not a tool or Jenkins plugin (as far as I know it), it is a group of people calling themselves the Microsoft Developer Network.  Have Jenkins continuously call Maven or something to build a MSI (WiX can be helpful there).  Then when releasing, pull the MSI from the Maven repository and use AD to install / distribute it.